# SQL Server - Case Expression and number formatting

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a script where I have the below case expression.

The strange thing that is happening is that SQL will cast all the results as Decimal 18,1. Even the metricid 1 records which should be cast as int.

```
   SELECT CASE 

    WHEN metricid = 1 then cast(result as int)
    WHEN metricid = 2 then cast(result as decimal(18,1)

    END as column1
   from sometable
```

I even added something like the following as the second condition which should not be evaluated because 1 does not = 3 (right?) but it still converts all the results to decimal:

```
 WHEN 1=3 and metricid = 2 then cast(result as decimal(18,1)
```

I think I broke the SQLs.... :(

Comment: You can only have one data-type per column. `column1` is a single column.

Comment: there's nothing strange about it, one column can have only one datatype

Comment: It might help if you understood the difference between a *statement* and an *expression*.  What you are using is a `CASE` *expression*.  As with any expression, it returns one value (per row).

Comment: Fixed just for you. the fact that it returns one value per row is irrelevant in the context of my question... thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL allows only one data type in a single column.  The possible solution might be converting your output to `VARCHAR`.  For example, consider the following example:

```
DECLARE @metricid INT
DECLARE @result INT

SET @metricid = 2 --(or 1)
SET @result = 20

SELECT CASE WHEN @metricid = 1 then CAST(CAST(@result as int) AS VARCHAR(55))
            WHEN @metricid = 2 then  CAST(CAST(@result as decimal(18,1)) AS VARCHAR(55))
            ELSE ''
       END Result
```

[The return type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) of a CASE expression is the highest precedence type from the set of types in result_expressions and the optional else_result_expression.  Precedence of data types can be checked [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx).

SQL-Server 2012 +

```
SELECT CASE WHEN @metricid = 1 then FORMAT(@result, '#')
            WHEN @metricid = 2 then FORMAT(@result, '#.0')
            ELSE ''
       END Result
```

Comment: THEN FORMAT(result, '#') AND THEN FORMAT(result,'#.0') works nicely in SQL 2012 + and little less writing of code

Comment: Thanks i'll try that! I was converting the final output as varchar but not each instance of the conditions inside the case! you da man. +1 for the precedence info also (instead of just saying "That's how SQL works"). I thought it had something to do with precedence (why it was picking 1 data type over the other.)

Comment: @Matt - I would love to use `FORMAT`.  Please consider editing my answer and placing your code under `SQL Server 2012` heading.  I have not had that version yet so it is not appropriate for me to steal your answer :)

Comment: I am fine with you stealing the answer, which is why I added as a comment to enhance, but I just edited for you.  Good answer!

Comment: @Matt I was able to get my query to work using the original answer. I'm on 2014 so I'll give FORMAT a try as well. Keeps the code looking a little neater and easier to read (less nested code is always a good thing). Thanks for the suggestion.